# Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount throws error resourcegroup not found

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

To create a SAS Token was the aim and required as a precondition setting desired storage as current storage:

Running the following command

```
Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $StorResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName
```

throws error:

> Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount : The Resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/yoursites' under resource group 'Default-Storage-EastUS' was not found.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $StorResourceGroupName -Name ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount], CloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.SetAzureRmCurrentStorageAccount

And this was throwing error for 
New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -Container $StorageContainer -Blob $blobname -Permission r -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(2.0) -FullUri

How to byepass this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I could think of 2 reasons why you may be getting this error:

1. Storage account does not belong to this resource group (as indicated by the error).
2. Storage account is a `Classic` storage account (I'm guessing this by the name of the Resource group).

Please see if one of them is indeed the case.

Comment: Yea, but why I switched to below context approach was that, it was not showing up on manage.windowsazure.com portal ( could be because it is not v1 and appears v2) but shown in portal.azure.com , and another reason was that connection key throwing base-64 unknown character while attempting to connect via Cloudberry to explore this account. Have you faced anything similiar on these storage types.

Comment: Also, below approach do not put the challenge of passing the resourcegroup id, appears to me the context object helps me on that.

Comment: The obvious advantage of using Resource Group approach over using StorageContext is that you don't have to remember the account key as it gets picked up automatically. Regarding the error you're facing, I'm not sure. It could be an issue with Cloudberry itself. Have you tried some other tools?

Answer (score 0):

The easy alternative I was able to apply was to create a storage context and pass the context parameter additionally.

Example :-

```
#Set Active Storage to Template Storage Context
$StorageKey = Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName;
$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageKey.Primary;
$now = Get-Date

#Create SAS token with temporary access 
New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -Container $servicetemplateStorageContainer -Blob $blobname -Context $StorageContext -Permission r -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(2.0) -FullUri
```

Hope this helps a straight reference for someone in similar scenario.